# Understanding Error in Model save

Tags: model, debugging

How can I debug or show the error trace of errors occur in calling `Model->save()`?

At the moment, I'm using logger to debug the execution.

```
$transaction = App::getModel('mygateway/transaction');
$transaction->setOrderId($order_id);
$transaction->setTransactionId($transaction_id);

Mage::log('saving', null, 'mygateway.log', true); 
$transaction->save();
Mage::log('saved', null, 'mygateway.log', true);
```

Is there something like: `$transaction->getLastError()`?

## Update (2nd Question)

How to debug `$transaction->save()` when it is executed without error, and yet the data is not stored in the database?

Comment: you can use exception handling (i.e, try, cache)

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaramR Thanks for the help. I tried to use the php exception handler and it works. `try {} catch (Exception $e) {$e->getMessage();}` will get the error message.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I debug.

1. [Read at the source code.](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.1.1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php#L416-L466)
2. Overwrite your resource model class `save` method. And **log** at each conditions.

   ```
   class Awesome_Cool_Model_Resource_Payment
       extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract 
   {
       protected function _constructor(){
           $this->_init('awesome_cool/payment', 'txn_id');
       }

       public function save(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object){
           // Copy the parent code
           // https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.1.1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php#L416-L466
           // ..........................................
           // ..........................................
           // ..........................................
           // ..........................................
           // ..........................................

           // Log Everywhere
           // Mage::log('Hi5', null, 'mylog.log');

       }
   }
   ```
3. Understand the code flow. (Why the code not executed at certain point)

> In my case, My issue is for [non increment primary key](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.1.1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php#L430-L434)
>
> solution:
>
> ```
> protected function _constructor(){
>     $this->_init('awesome_cool/payment', 'txn_id');
>     $this->_isPkAutoIncrement = false;
> }
> ```

Comment: The isPkAutoIncrement was exactly my issue too.

Answer (score 1):

As we disused in the comment.

Use exception handler to catch the error.(i.e., try, catch)

```
$transaction = App::getModel('mygateway/transaction');
$transaction->setOrderId($order_id);
$transaction->setTransactionId($transaction_id);
try{ 
   $transaction->save();
}
catch(Exception $error){
   Mage::log($error->getMessage(), null, 'yourlogfile.log');
}
```

Comment: How to debug an issue when there is no error and yet no data is saved after `save()` is called?

Comment: Get data before save `$transaction->get data();` by using this you can check your data is set to that variable or not.

Comment: The data looks good. It has every field needed. I need to know why they still fail.

Comment: Have you check that in database?

Comment: That's the first thing I do to check whether the data is saved or not

Comment: [I'm logging the SQL queries.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4460639/764592) The insert script was not even queried in the log.

Comment: @yeo can you show your entire module so that we can find the solution

Comment: You may did mistake in your module collection.

Comment: How could collection be involved in the `save()` or how to debug this?

Comment: Could not able to find without seeing ur  code

Comment: Can show ur table columns name